# Variation of the opaque forest problem (a.k.a farmyard problem)

Tags: geometry, optimization, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, combinatorial-geometry

I was wondering about the following variation of the [opaque forest problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_forest_problem) (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66486/the-farmyard-problem/) and [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721087/puzzle-cable-in-the-field/) for previous questions) :

> What is the least length set of segments that will intersect every straight line passing through a unit square $]0,1[^2$ in at least **two** different points ? $\tag 1$

The best known solution for the original problem does not satisfy the condition, since the grey line intersects only one time the set of $4$ segments :

[image]

Actually I didn't found a better solution to $(1)$ than a "trivial" one, which has total length 4. Does anyone can find a better solution, or does it seem to be the best we can do? I tried to do it by contradiction, but I got no result.

Thank you in advance for your comments !

Comment: Trivially, each of the four corners must be a vertex of two segments in this case.

Comment: @Travis : thank you for your comment. But this doesn't mean that a lower bound is $4$, or am I missing something trivial ?

Comment: No, or anyway if it does, I don't see why either. That said, I would be mildly surprised if there's a solution better than the trivial one in this case.